# Proper Steps To Upgrade My Server 2008 R2 Machine From HHD To SSD

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, raid, ssd, drivers, device

I'm working on upgrading a server's hard drive from a standard HHD to an SSD drive.  I have cloned the drive with a program called "EaseUS Todo Backup Free 8.6" (which I think does a bunch of extra steps than just cloning the partitions) and that seemed to work fine.  The issues that I'm running into is my server currently is running a hardware RAID 1 array (MIRROR) and I have decided to move to a software RAID so that I can use the TRIM function with my new SSD drives.

The issue is when I set my BIOS from RAID to AHCI windows refuses to boot and ends up at a STOP screen (BSOD) with error code 0x0000007B.
[image]

I'm trying my best to resolve this issue and have been looking all over the web for answers.  What I ended up finding was that my server (Intel X38ML) currently has the RAID drivers installed and NOT the IDE drivers OR the AHCI drivers that I actually need.  So this BSOD is all I get when I change it from anything but RAID.  Both IDE and AHCI settings in the BIOS give me this BSOD.

I have been to [this site](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/16098/Intel-Matrix-RAID-and-AHCI-Driver-for-Windows-) to grab the drivers I thought I needed as suggested by another site, but those did not work for me.  So I tried to grab older drivers specific for my board (I guess) from [this site](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/20768) which is also an Intel site, but those did not help either.  Everytime I try to install these two drivers I get the following...

[image]
[image]

My device manager currently looks like this...

[image]

I'm looking for something like this in the end...

[image]

Any ideas?  How can I load those AHCI drivers on my OS to be able to switch to AHCI in the BIOS?  Or am I going about this the wrong way?

---

UPDATE

I thought it was worth adding to the original question...  I have already completed the required registry edits to enable AHCI.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\Msahci
- Edit REG_DWORD called "Start", change value from 3 to 0.

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\IastorV
- Edit REG_DWORD called "Start", change value from 3 to 0.
- Note this key did not exist on my server so I took no action.
```

Comment: Nitpick: your issue is not in moving from HDD to SSD, but in changing your controller configuration so what Windows detects a different controller and doesn't have the proper drivers to boot from it; this is a well known issue with Intel onboard controllers and isn't related to what type of disk is actually used to store data.

Comment: No disrespect, but isn't that like saying "You're issue is not that you ran out of gas, but that you have no gas in the car."?  Seeing as how I'm trying to change my hard drives from HHD to SSD and the SSD drives need the AHCI turned on with RAID turned off.  As my subject suggests, I'm trying to get the proper steps in changing from HHD to SSD.  This issue is in fact an issue that directly relates to the end goal.  It's necessary.

Comment: Just saying it would have been exactly the same if you were moving from RAID HDDs to non-RAID HDDs; and no issue would instead have happened if you were using SSDs with the controller still configured for RAID mode. The issue is in using RAID or AHCI mode, not in using HDDs or SSDs.

Comment: I see what your saying, and yes you are 100% correct.  Though it is possible to use SSD drives with RAID I have seen everywhere that doing so is a VERY bad idea.  Your drive life will not last as long and you would see major performance issues within a month on installation (unless you keep about 30% of unallocated space on the new SSD).  So I have always thought of SSD as SSD/AHCI/TRIM all combined as one and needed to perform as intended.  I currently have a RAID config and unfortunately will be moving away from my hardware raid because of this.

Comment: There's so much bad information/misinformation here.

Comment: @ewwhite , well that's just not helpful...  Why not tell us what is "bad information".

Comment: [SSDs can be used with RAID for many workloads](http://serverfault.com/q/712922/13325). I highly suggest that you do, in fact.

Comment: I was simply going by comunity posts, such as the one located at http://blog.serverfault.com/2011/02/09/our-storage-decision/ which shows serverfaults own server setup.  Within the first couple of comments people are talking about EXACTLY what I stated...  Has that now changed?

Comment: @ArvoBowen That information on the SF blog is old and probably not a good practice *today* either. I know that's not helpful to hear.

Comment: @ewwhite No worries, I figured things have changed in the years since SSDs came to the open market with storage capacity in the terabyte range.  I was just trying to find out the best practice (as of today) that would allow me to replace my old HHD with my new SSD.  I was hoping not to reinstall the OS.  :/