# Swapping out a HP H240 host bus adapter to a P420?

Tags: raid, hp, ssd

Does anyone know if it is possible to keep the current raid configuration if swapping from the H240?

It's currently running raid1+0 with 4xSSD's and I've noticed the poor write performance compared to the read performance (200MB/s compared to 1.2GB/s) and when searching around noticed that it's because it's a HBA, but the server is fairly mission-critical so rebuilding and recovering from backup wouldn't be ideal.

I know you can swap between other P series cards but unsure if it would work from a H.

Thanks

Comment: The HBA is capable of fine speeds. What specific SSDs are you using?

Comment: Samsung PM883 960GB.

This is where I got the info about HBA being poor for write performance. (https://serverfault.com/questions/728562/slow-write-performance-with-hp-h240-hba-using-internal-storage-with-raid-5-ssds)